# Makefile: $subst in dependency list

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile which looks roughly like this:

```
FIGURES = A1_B1_C1.eps A2_B2_C2.eps A3_B3_C3.eps
NUMBERS = 1 2 3

all : $(FIGURES)

%.eps : $(foreach num, $(NUMBERS), $(subst B, $(num), %).out)
    # my_program($+, $@);

%.out :
```

The point is that the file names of my figures contain certain information (A, B, C) and that each figure is created by my_program from several (in the example 3) files.
While the filename of each figure has the format `Ax_Bx_Cx.eps`, the names of the data files to create the figures from look like this:

```
Ax_1x_Cx.out
Ax_2x_Cx.out
Ax_3x_Cx.out
```

So for each figure, I need a dynamically created dependency list with several file names. In other words, my desired output for the example above would be:

> # my_program(A1_11_C1.out A1_21_C1.out A1_31_C1.out, A1_B1_C1.eps);
>
> # my_program(A2_12_C2.out A2_22_C2.out A2_32_C2.out, A2_B2_C2.eps);
>
> # my_program(A3_13_C3.out A3_23_C3.out A3_33_C3.out, A3_B2_C3.eps);

Unfortunately, the `subst` command seems to be ignored, for the output looks like this:

> # my_program(A1_B1_C1.out A1_B1_C1.out A1_B1_C1.out, A1_B1_C1.eps);
>
> # my_program(A2_B2_C2.out A2_B2_C2.out A2_B2_C2.out, A2_B2_C2.eps);
>
> # my_program(A3_B3_C3.out A3_B3_C3.out A3_B3_C3.out, A3_B3_C3.eps);

I had a look at [this possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755842/makefile-string-substitution-in-dependency-not-working) but figured that the answer cannot help me, since I am using `%` and not `$@`, which should be ok in the prerequisites.

Clearly I am getting something wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do fancy prerequisite manipulations you need at least make-3.82 which supports [Secondary Expansion feature](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

```
FIGURES = A1_B1_C1.eps A2_B2_C2.eps A3_B3_C3.eps
NUMBERS = 1 2 3

all : $(FIGURES)

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(FIGURES) : %.eps : $$(foreach num,$$(NUMBERS),$$(subst B,$$(num),$$*).out)
    @echo "my_program($+, $@)"

%.out :
    touch $@
```

Output:

```
$ make
touch A1_11_C1.out
touch A1_21_C1.out
touch A1_31_C1.out
my_program(A1_11_C1.out A1_21_C1.out A1_31_C1.out, A1_B1_C1.eps)
touch A2_12_C2.out
touch A2_22_C2.out
touch A2_32_C2.out
my_program(A2_12_C2.out A2_22_C2.out A2_32_C2.out, A2_B2_C2.eps)
touch A3_13_C3.out
touch A3_23_C3.out
touch A3_33_C3.out
my_program(A3_13_C3.out A3_23_C3.out A3_33_C3.out, A3_B3_C3.eps)
```