# Use 'subst' in a multiline makefile bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I read this question: [Makefile: $subst in dependency list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14731869/827263), but I still can't make my shell script work correctly.

I have a `makefile` with a line with the contents:

```
#@public_detailed@|test_create|Syntax: commoncmdsyntax test_create test_name=<test-name>
```

A target runs a multiline bash script, where the `commoncmdsyntax` must be replaced by a string containing words and spaces.

In the script, I use cut to assign to a variable `desc` the following string:

```
Syntax: commoncmdsyntax test_create test_name=<test-name>
```

The problem is that `commoncmdsyntax` is not replaced by `new text` here:

```
$(subst commoncmdsyntax,new text,$$desc)
```

I also tried to replace it by a single word, like `XX`, but it also does not work.

Comment: please edit your question to show the output of `make -v`. Good luck.

Comment: `make -v` reports that I'm using `GNU Make 3.81`

Comment: Secondary expansion is available in make 3.81.

Comment: That sample line is a comment. Secondary expansion only occurs on target prerequisites. Can you show us the snippet of your makefile in question here because I am having a very hard time understanding what you are trying to do and what you are working with. It sounds like you are trying to cross make/shell boundaries as well as not understanding secondary expansion correctly.

Comment: As I commented the answer below, from Beta, I used `sed`. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is the `#` of the line `#@public_detailed@|...` there on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

The `subst` function (as in `$(subst commoncmdsyntax,new text,$$desc)`) is a Make function, so Make will perform the substitution *before running any rule* and therefore before your script assigns a value to `desc`. So even if secondary expansion worked the way you seem to think it will, this approach would still fail.

If you want to perform a substitution within something made by a shell script (in a recipe), the sensible way is to do so within the recipe:

```
echo $dest | sed 's/commoncmdsyntax/new text/'
```

We can give you a more detailed solution if you give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: I gave up using `subst`, and used `sed` exactely this way. Thanks!